# Storing GPO files and scripts and file references within scripts

Tags: group-policy

We have some older GPOs which relied on files stored in a fileserver share.  So, there are references to those files and *within* some of those files there are similar references to files stored in a fileserver share.

The problem is that if/when the fileserver reference or share reference change, then it has to be cleaned up.  That's not very forward-thinking.  Also, it most likely depends on ACLs / Security Groups which can change and don't belong in this context.

How to best avoid system-level changes like this?
Is \domain\netlogon a better location and ALSO a reliable reference within scripts?
I don't want to have to worry about Security Groups either....

Comment: Why does it have to be one or the other? And why is it "changing"? Maybe it shouldn't "change" if it is used to perform a function, like run a script during logon. Why would netlogon be used for a policy-based script? I keep all files associated with a policy in the same policy folder, but it's not uncommon to have multiple scripts, including scripts local IT can maintain without updating a GPO.

Comment: One or the other referring to which items?

Comment: One or the other referring to which items?
Things *do* change and some changes have unforeseen impacts.  So, the objective here is to avoid such impact by choosing a more stable location.  The question is: where?  *I* don't know why netlogon would be used for a policy-based script nor "why not?".  Just my ignorance.  I guess the suggestion is that multiple locations are a better idea.  OK, so which locations?  That's the objective of the question.